# Метод класса создается для каждого объекта класса или одна для всех?

Tags: c++, классы

Методы класса создаются для каждого объекта отдельно или они создаются в начале программы, и доступ к ним осуществляется только через объект класса?

```
class Tt {
    int x, y, z;
public:
    Tt() {
        reset();
    }

    void reset() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
};
```

Например sizeof от класса в этом случае будет равен 12.

При вызове метода класса компилятор такую запись `some_name.reset()` конвертирует в такую: `reset(&some_name)` Получается что метод(не статический) это обычная функция которая принадлежит классу и доступ к которой осуществляется только через объект класса, у которой левый параметр это указатель на текущий класс

Comment: "Метод" (функция-член) — это же просто **код**. Естественно, он общий для всего класса, для всех объектов. Не создается же какая-нибудь функция типа `sqrt` для каждого аргумента отдельно?

Comment: ни для каждого объекта  и ни в начале программы _ не создаются. Создаются объекты, а  методы  есть просто запись  о действии, в конкретной единице  трансляции

Comment: @ARHovsepyan методы создаются на этапе определения класса? Время жизни их ограничивается файлом, в котором они определены?

Comment: @Kurr200,  время жизни вашего комментария чем ограничивается?.. Пока есть сайт и не был удален _ он будет,  пока им не пользуешься он  просто не видимый. И класс и комментарий есть набор слов(код и есть набор слов).  Они есть, пока вы их не удалили или не удалили то, где их записали.

Comment: А каково время жизни упомянутой выше функции `sqrt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов одного метода класса разных экземпляров этого класса имеет одно и то же расположение в памяти и соответственно одинаковый адрес вызова.

Но. Современные компиляторы хорошо оптимизируют, и не редко, что некоторые методы вообще не имеют отдельного адреса вызова, т.к. они заинлайнены в другой код. В данном случае, такой метод имеет множественное инжектирование в скомпилированном коде, но эта множественность зависит не от различных экземпляров класса, а от точек вызова этого метода.

Comment: У inline - функций вроде как есть тело, просто оно вставляется на место вызова и адрес у них вроде как присутствует. Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Компиляторы с кодом творят все что угодно, и это где-то упоминалось в стандарте, что результат компиляции может быть какой угодно до тех пор, пока программа ведет себя согласно определениям стандарта. Объявили вы функцию, сохранили указатель на нее в переменную. Переменную нигде не использовали и компилятор ее заоптимизировал. Значит и адрес на функцию ему уже не требуется. Согласно стандарту адрес у инлайн-функций одинаковый. Но если вы его не сохраняли и не завязывали логику на него, то когда начнете искать эту функцию в ассемблерном представлении программы, то можете эту функцию и не найти.